# PHP Использование родительской переменной класса в конструкторе наследника

Tags: php, ооп, классы

```
<?php
    class BaseClass {
        protected $value1;
        public function set_value1($new_value1) {
            $this->value1 = $new_value1;
        }
        public function get_value1() {
            return $this->value1;
        }
    }
?>
```

---

```
<?php
    require_once "BaseClass.php";

    class NextClass extends BaseClass {
        public $value3;
        public function __construct($this->value1, $val3) {
            $this->value3 = $val3;
        }
    }

    $r = new NextClass("test","Cat");
    var_dump($r->get_value1());
?>
```

Хочу использовать переменную $value1 в конструкторе наследника.

Ошибка в этой строчке: `public function __construct($this->value1, $val3)`

Ошибка `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')' in`

Что-то я недопонимаю в ООП PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут ещё нет this, поскольку это ссылка на свой класс. Она доступна только внутри конструктора.

Чтобы использовать value1 из родительского класса, её надо сделать protected, а не private, и в дочернем классе спокойно к ней обращаться по $this->value1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
    protected $value1;
    public function set_value1($new_value1) {
        $this->value1 = $new_value1;
    }
    public function get_value1() {
        return $this->value1;
    }
}

class NextClass extends BaseClass {
    public $value3;
    public function __construct($value, $val3) {
        $this->value3 = $val3;
        $this->value1 = $value;
    }
}

$r = new NextClass("test","Cat");
var_dump($r->get_value1());
```